# Laravel collection returning empty array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Dear stackoverflow colleagues,

I am having difficulty returning a set of data from laravel.
Basically what I am trying to achieve is:

1. Having one array of users (at the moment 2 users) I am looping through this array, and getting the username.
2. Using this username, foreach name I am looking for it's ID and running a function that return for said ID every order created by this user account (only total value of said orders).
3. Return for each user an object like:

   ```
   {'username': name_in_the_array,'totalPrice': value,}
   ```

Instead I get an empty result, although the $data variable has 1 value, at least.

Below the code of the Model/Controller and results

```
public static function getOrdersUser($startDate, $endDate, $user){
    $orders = Order::whereBetween('orders.created_at', [new Carbon($startDate), new Carbon($endDate)])
        ->select(DB::raw('COALESCE(NULLIF(order_article_configurations.special_price, 0), order_article_configurations.price) * order_article_configurations.quantity AS totalPrice, orders.user_id'))
        ->join('order_articles', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_articles.order_id')
        ->join('order_article_configurations', 'order_articles.id', '=', 'order_article_configurations.order_article_id')
        ->where('orders.user_id', $user)
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('orders.is_quotation', '=', '0')
                ->orWhereNull('orders.is_quotation');
        })
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->whereNull('orders.deleted_at')
                ->orWhereNull('order_articles.deleted_at')
                ->orWhereNull('order_article_configurations.deleted_at');
        })
        ->get('totalPrice', 'orders.user_id');

    return $orders;
}
```

Next Controller:

```
    public static function getOrdersUser(Request $request = null) {
    if (isset($request)) {
        $startDate = $request['start_date'];
        $endDate = $request['end_date'];
    } else {
        $startDate = Carbon::now()->subDays(30);
        $endDate = Carbon::now();
    }
    $users = ['merijn', 'stefan'];

    $data = null;
    $data = collect($data);
    $sum = 0;
    foreach($users as $user) {
        $userID = collect(DB::select("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$user'"))->first();
        $userID = $userID->id;

        $data->username = $user;

        $value = Dashboard::getOrdersUser($startDate, $endDate, $userID);
        foreach ($value as $x) {

            $sum += $x->totalPrice;

        }

        $data->price = $sum;

    }

    return $data;
}
```

If I use `dd()` on `$data`, the result is:

```
Psy Shell v0.8.2 (PHP 7.1.7 — cli) by Justin Hileman
New version is available (current: v0.8.2, latest: v0.8.17)
>>> $x = App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::getOrdersUser();
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#895
  #items: []
  +"username": "stefan"
  +"price": 258090.16
}
```

But `return $data` return [].

The expected result I would like to be:

```
{ 'username':username,
  'price': total value }
{ 'username': next_username,
   'price': users total value
```

I appreciate all of your inputs.
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure `getOrdersUser` returns any values? Try `dd`'ing the value at the end of this function.

Comment: Yes, it returns some values. In a Collection I can see :       #attributes: array:2 [
        "totalPrice" => "1900.00"
        "user_id" => 27
      ]
, of course, multiple times different values, as the specific user has more than 1 order created.